TYPO3 register User via JSON
I need to create a TYPO3 extension with which I execute a method via the url www.domain.com/addusers, which reads me a JSON file and uses the data it contains to create a new frontend user. What is the best way to proceed? I thought of something like this:
<?php
namespace Namespace\Namespace\Controller;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Type\ContextualFeedbackSeverity;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment;

class FrontendUserController extends ActionController {

    public function __construct(
        private readonly ConnectionPool $connectionPool,
    ) {}

    public function registerAction($jsonString) {
        $jsonFilePath = Environment::getVarPath() . '/storage/data/users.json';

        $jsonData = file_get_contents($jsonFilePath);
        $userData = json_decode($jsonData, true);

        $queryBuilder = $this->connectionPool->getQueryBuilderForTable('fe_users');

        $newUser = [
            'username' => $userData['email'],
            'email' => $userData['email'],
            'password' => $userData['password'],
            'usergroup' => '1',
            'first_name' => $userData['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $userData['name'],
            'gender' => $userData['gender'],
            'pid' => '0',
            'tstamp' => time(),
            'crdate' => time(),
            'deleted' => '0',
            'hidden' => '0',
            'starttime' => '0',
            'endtime' => '0'
        ];

        $createUser = $databaseConnection->createQueryBuilder();
        $createUser
            ->insert('fe_users')
            ->values($newUser)
            ->executeStatement();

        $this->addFlashMessage('Created.', '', ContextualFeedbackSeverityAlias::OK);
    }
}

The routeEnhancer:
routeEnhancers:
  Plugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Plugin
    plugin: FrontendUser
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/addusers'
        _controller: 'FrontendUser::register'
        _arguments:
          jsonString: '@widget_0/currentUserJsonString'
    defaultController: 'FrontendUser::register'
    aspects:
      jsonString:
        type: Argument

I'll get this error:
(1/1) #1538079482 OutOfRangeException
No aspect found for Argument

Maybe i need some more DB fields for the frontend user.
I have to extend the table.
This is a demo
[
      {
        "name": "Name",
        "first_name": "First Name",
        "gender": "m",
        "email": "email@email",
        "password": "$2a$10$7gEoOnaYRigcziqrR91\/7elUC9BSNpVd1rO\/ysg1YiJlERHV9wybi",
        "usergroup": 1,
        "customer_id": 123,
        "institution": "institution",
        "active": true,
        "deleted": 0
      }

]


BTW: That sounds very unsecure to me :-) But nevertheless. I think the problem is your routeEnhancer. Try without routing first.
